# C# Video Player

Tags: c#, .net, video

I am writing a program that is designed to play videos (not sure if there are consistent formats) in C#.net.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any good libraries that would be able to play multiple codecs with aspecting and cropping options, but no direct controls (or at least hide-able)?

Comment: take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zMoviePlayer.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using DirectShow APIs, there is wrapper for .NET: [DirectShowNET Library](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/about.html)

Comment: that looks perfect, DirectShow support most of the codecs that vlc supports (sure a few are lacking, but the important ones)?

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can try [ffmpeg][1][1]: http://ffmpeg.org/ this is a Tools to record, convert, stream and play multimedia content.

Comment: sounds interesting, im searching for some wrappers at the moment, but do you know of any?